Python socket: Client and server unable to connect
I'm working on a simple data transfer program using Python sockets. I have a server and a client script, but they're unable to establish a connection. Below are the sample codes for both the server and client
Server Code:
import socket

addr = ('0.0.0.0', 8080)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as server_socket:
    server_socket.bind(addr)
    server_socket.listen()
    print("Server is listening on port", addr[1])
    client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
    print("Connected to", client_address)
    data = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print("Received:", data.decode('utf-8'))
    client_socket.close()

Client code:
import socket

addr = ('my_ip', 8080)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as client_socket:
    client_socket.connect(addr)
    message = "Hello, server!"
    client_socket.sendall(message.encode('utf-8'))
    print("Data sent to the server")

Error:
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond


Please copy-paste the error message you see when you run these programs.

@Robᵩ error is added

'my_ip' is not a valid address.  If my_ip has the address, then try f'{my_ip}'.

@cup 'my_ip' is my ip address, and not  going to reveal it, that why i wrote 'my_ip'

It is unclear what you are trying to do. Connect to localhost on the same machine, connect to the LAN-IP within the LAN, connect to the public IP from within the same LAN, connect to the public IP from outside, ... ? Depending on what you are trying to do it might be wrong IP, firewalls in the way, no support for NAT hairpinning in the router, no forwarding rules in the router for access from outside, ...

@SteffenUllrich My aim is to create a controller, by which I can control my pc from any where by my handheld device.

@CodeMaven42: In this case you would need to have a) port forwarding (unclear if you have) and b) a router with support for NAT hairpinning to access it from inside the same LAN (most routers don't have this) and c) allow incoming connections on the firewall on the internal device (unknown).

I was able to get your code working by using localhost for the ip value. Is that sufficient for your testing? perhaps you are not accessing the correct ip address / port in the case of running this code and trying to access a remote location:
client
import socket

addr = ("localhost", 8080)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as client_socket:
    client_socket.connect(addr)
    message = "Hello, server!"
    client_socket.sendall(message.encode("utf-8"))
    print("Data sent to the server")

server
import socket

addr = ("localhost", 8080)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as server_socket:
    server_socket.bind(addr)
    server_socket.listen()
    print("Server is listening on port", addr[1])
    client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
    print("Connected to", client_address)
    data = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print("Received:", data.decode("utf-8"))
    client_socket.close()

client output
Data sent to the server

server output
Server is listening on port 8080
Connected to ('127.0.0.1', 48326)
Received: Hello, server!


Ya i know it works for localhost, but I want it for my public ip

Could you be more specific? If I understand you correctly, you want to access your server on your public ip from some remote network? In that case, have you properly set up port forwarding for that specific port? You can test whether the appropriate port is open with websites like this. After confirming the correct port is open, you also have to make sure that it is correctly set up in your router settings. There's a lot of resources online about port forwarding.

@CodeMaven42 that information should be added to the question. There’s nothing wrong with the code shown and we don’t know your setup.
